# How to specify the item's style in gridview when the pointer over it

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I use gridview to list all the items, I want to realize an effect that when the pointer over an item, it appears as a style and after the pointer moved off, the style disappear, any one can provide me some suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to change the ItemContainerStyle of the grid. To do this do the following:

Right click on the GridView on the left and select Edit Additional Templates, Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle), Edit a Copy.

In the style that gets generated you'll find a VisualStateGroup called "Hover".  These are the changes that take place to the container when a user is hovering over an item.